# How to handle 1 inch gap between bathtub tile and drywall?

Tags: bathroom, repair, walls, ceramic-tile

I have a new tub put in, and tile to go with it in my tub area.  The tile is only in my tub area.  I have a one inch gap between the tile and the drywall.  How do I make it so this edge looks nice.  On the other side of the tub, the gap is about 1 inch.  The bathroom is small, and the one inch gap will stick out.[image: 1 inch gap between bathtub tile and drywall]

Answer (score 2):

There is a 1" quarter round ceramic available. Local home centers here stock it.

You could also rip down bullnose edging.

If you're bold enough, you could try to mix up some colored sanded grout on the stiff side, and try to run a chamferred edge detail.

Lastly, although it might be ugly, you could install vinyl quarter round.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 exactly right. I added photos to help clarify terms for the OP. Go to a tile shop and you will find options.

Answer (score 0):

One option in addition to bullnose tile from other posts would be to use a metallic edge trim. Search "tile edging trim" at Home Depot or your favorite retailer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  For the wall, I opted to extend the wall to the end of the bathroom.  I appreciate the help and quidance.  I had trouble matching my tile so   I went with extending the one wall that has a inch gap to the end of the bathroom.